# For Each Loop update cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello guys I'm trying to update some of my cell with currentdate, so i did the following, but was not able to update the cell.

EDIT: to add in the missing function from the entire code.

```
Sub GetField32AFromCell()

    For Each Cell In Worksheets("MM_Creation_Success").Range("G2:G9")

        'Get cell which is right side of the current cell in for each loop
         Dim nextRange As Variant: nextRange = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        'split the value of the cell into string array
         Dim splitString() As String: splitString = SplitStringByNewLine(Cell)

         For Each sString In splitString

             Dim newLine As String: newLine = sString
             newLine = TryGetField32A(newLine)

             If Not newLine = "" Then

                 Dim newDateString As String: newDateString = GetCurrentDate("yymmdd")
                 Dim new32AField As String: new32AField = Mid(newLine, 7)

                 new32AField = newDateString + new32AField
                 'Set nextRange = new32AField
                 'MsgBox (nextRange)
             End If
         Next
     Next

End Sub


    Public Function SplitStringByNewLine(stringArray As Variant) As String()
        SplitStringByNewLine = Split(stringArray, Chr(10))
    End Function

    Public Function TryGetField32A(newLine As String) As String
        If newLine Like ("*:32A:*") Then
        TryGetField32A = Mid(newLine, Len("*32A::"), Len(newLine))
        'MsgBox ("Found Tag 32A: " + field32AVal)
    End If
    End Function

    Public Function GetCurrentDate(dateFormat As String) As String
        Dim todayDate As String: todayDate = Format(Date, dateFormat,         vbMonday, vbUseSystem)
        GetCurrentDate = todayDate
        'MsgBox ("Current Date in Format (" + dateFormat + "): " + todayDate)
    End Function
```

Comment: aren't you getting an error here `splitString = SplitStringByNewLine(Cell)` ? trying to assign in to an array

Comment: Sorry I forgotten to paste the other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to put `new32AField` into a cell represented by `nextRange`, then you first need to make sure `nextRange` actually represents a cell and not contains its value:

```
Dim nextRange As Range: Set nextRange = Cell.Offset(0, 1)
```

And then you need to set its value, not try to change the represented range:

```
nextRange.Value = new32AField
```